# objective c popen

Tags: objective-c, popen

im looking to execute to execute command line commands from objective c. I know that popen can do this however I am have trouble trying to read and display what the data as an NSString. can anyone tell me how to do this or give me a native objective c function that is equivalent?

I probably should have mentioned im trying to write an application for a jailbroken iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`NSTask`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).